# how to prompt password manager for username and password?

Tags: html

I have a html form for register user, what attribute should I put to prompt password manager (google/lastpass/onepass/etc) that the email address will be used as username upon submit?

```html
<form>
    <input type='text' placeholder='email address'><br>
    <input type='text' placeholder='first name'><br>
    <input type='text' placeholder='last name'><br>
    <input type='text' placeholder='postcode'><br>
    <input type='password' placeholder='password'><br>
    <input type='password' placeholder='password again'><br>
    <button type='submit'>register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

Most password managers use the `name` attribute for this purpose.

You need to provide one anyway so that the control can be successful and the data submitted to the server.

Comment: so for the emailaddress input, what is the value of the name attribute should I put in?

Comment: Anything suggestive of an email address, such as `email`